# How can I remove ion-checkbox background & border color in IONIC 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic4

Customize ion-checkbox background & border in IONIC 4

**My code:**

```
.checkbox-icon {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: please add any picture like you want

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
<ion-checkbox color="primary"></ion-checkbox>
```

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox/#css-custom-properties

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox